# Reading a directory file in C

Tags: c, linux, unix, filesystems

I'm trying to write a small program to show me the internal representation of a directory in linux (debian, specifically). The idea was a small C program using open(".", O_RDONLY), but this seems to give no output. The program is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        int fd = open(argv[1],O_RDONLY,0 );
        char buf;

        printf("%i\n",fd);

        while(read(fd, &buf, 1) > 0)

                printf("%x ", buf);


        putchar('\n');
}
```

When I run it on regular files it works as expected, but on a directory such as ".", it gives no output. The value of fd is 3 (as expected) but the call to read returns -1.

Why isn't this working, and how could I achieve to read the internal representation?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe that your code (or an equivalent) might have worked long time ago (perhaps in the 1980s or 1970s), in an implementation specific way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For handling directories, you need to use `opendir`/`readdir`/`closedir`. Read the corresponding man pages for more infos.

To check whether a filename corresponds to a directory, you first need to call `stat` for the filename and check whether it's a directory (`S_ISDIR(myStatStruc.st_mode)`).

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: Right, but it isn't portable. By contrast, the functions I've cited are in POSIX.

Answer (score 2):

Directories are a filesystem specific representation and are part of the file system. On extfs, they are a table of string/inode pairs, unlike files which have blocks of data(that you read using your code above).

To read directory-specific information in C, you need to use dirent.h .
Look at this page for more information
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/dirent.h.html

On POSIX systems, the system call "stat" would give you all the information about an inode on the filesystem(file/directory/etc.)